# Azure Data Factory - Nameless Json array

Tags: arrays, azure, rest, oracle-adf

Working with an API that returns a nameless Json Array. This data then needs to be converted into a table format so that it can be written to a database. For this I have been trying to use Azure Data Factory and the flatten data flow block. The problem is that this block cannot pick up the unroll by or unroll root values as the array does not have a name. The error I get is "At least one of unrollby or unrollMultiple expression expected" .
[it won't let me select Unroll information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqsro.png)

[And in the configuration the unroll is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEM9N.png)

This is not complicated functionality - in other parts of the data flow ADF recognizes the columns no problem. The inputs and outputs are correct .

I have tried coding in the unroll values using dynamic content but not sure exactly what to put there. I have tried body.null and a few others

Answer (score 0):

I tried with following sample JSON which have nameless array and got same result as yours.

[image]

Data flow is not identifying the nameless JSON values but got the remaining values.

[image]

As a workaround, you can first name your JSON array and store it any intermediate storage like Blob and give it to dataflow.

As you are getting data from API, use a web activity to get the JSON. Here I have used lookup from blob which will give JSON object as a whole array for this demonstration.

Now, using set variable activity replace the `""` with `"<key>"` with the following expression.

```
@json(replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),'""','"key1"'))
```

I have stored the above JSON array in an array variable. Change the above expression as per your web activity expression (you can store it as a string itself in a string variable).

[image]

Now, I have got the result like below.

[image]

Store this in a json file in Blob storage. To do that use copy activity.

In Copy activity source use a csv file with 1 header and 1 row and use the above result in additonal column.

[image]

Here I have used the `string(variable('arr')[0])` as I am getting this value from an array. If you are storing the replaced value in a string, you can use it directly.

For copy activity sink, use another Delimited text dataset with the following configurations.

[image]

Now, execute the pipeline and you can see we got JSON file in the Blob storage.

[image]

After copy activity, use dataflow activity and give the above JSON to dataflow as source and you can flatten it as per your requirement.

As another alternative, use SQL script to store the JSON into the database. Use `openjson()` like functions in script or stored procedure activity.